# Disable inline editing on a list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

does anybody know if there is a way in SharePoint 2010 to disable inline editing on a list?
Or, is there a way to prevent users with contribute permissions on a list from creating list views with inline editing enabled?

Our users have contribute permission on the list so simply disabling inline editing for a particular View won't work because they can just create a new View with inline editing enabled.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want this disabled?  That is, is it causing any harm?

Comment: Yes because users can circumvent our required fields by creating a view without the required fields and then using inline edit to create a new item and not have to enter in those required fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninherit the permissions to this list and make a new permission level called "Custom Contributor" and edit it to copy the "Contributor" permission level, then remove the "Manage Personal Views" Here's a walkthrough:

1. Navigate to the list you would like to apply this on.
2. Go to the List/Library tab on the Library/List Tools section at the top of the page.
3. Click the Library/List Permissions
4. Click Stop Inheriting Permissions.
5. Click Site Actions -> Site Permissions
6. Goto Permission Levels -> Contributor -> Copy Permission Level (Bottom of Page)
7. Name this "Custom Contributor" and uncheck "Manage Personal Views  -  Create, change, and delete personal views of lists."
8. Go back to the library/list permissions -> Click on the user you want to change, uncheck Contributor (or other more permissive access), and check "Custom Contributor".
9. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there would be a way to disable inline editing while still allowing view creation, but oh well.